# ElasticSearch + Node on Mac OS X Yosemite: JRE crash?

Tags: node.js, macos, elasticsearch, jvm, coredump

Somewhat baffled by this one, probably because I haven't often encountered a JRE core dump.

I'm using the official ElasticSearch module for Node.js, and attempting to create a new document in one of my indices.

My Node app appears to connect to the ES instance just fine, but when I execute the `create` request, my JRE bites the dust!  Here's the error spit out by Node:

```
Elasticsearch INFO: 2015-12-16T21:40:47Z
  Adding connection to http://my.server.address/:9200
Elasticsearch DEBUG: 2015-12-16T21:40:53Z
  starting request { method: 'POST',
    path: '/test/document',
    body: { foo: 'bar' },
    query: { op_type: 'create' } }

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000001004f3616, pid=40975, tid=1299
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b15) (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [node+0x4f3616]  _ZN4node8debugger5Agent14MessageHandlerERKN2v85Debug7MessageE+0x34
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Path/To/My/App/hs_err_pid42140.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

And here are [the contents of the core dump](https://gist.github.com/MITREDan/18a44d8d58b744465df8).

Comment: What versions of ES and Node.js do you have?

Comment: @Val Node 5.2.0 and ElasticSearch 2.0.0.

Comment: Looks like there's a bug with a `console.log` statement causing this in node 5.2.0: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4261 . Any chance to try Node 5.1.1 and see if that solves?

Comment: @Val will give that a shot & report back, thanks!

Comment: @Val that did it! Could you repost that as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a bug with a `console.log()` statement causing this in node 5.2.0: http://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4261

If you downgrade to Node 5.1.1, you should be good to go.